# The cardinality of an algebraic extension $E$ of a field $F$ cannot exceed the cardinality of $F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I want to show that let $F \subseteq E$ be an algebraic extension of a field $F$, then the cardinality of $E$ cannot exceed the cardinality of $F[X]$.

The proof this assertion as follows. Let $S$ be the set of all ordered pairs $(f,\alpha)$, where $f\in F[X]$ is nonzero and $\alpha \in E$ with $f(\alpha)=0$. Since for each polynomial f, the number of $\alpha$ such that $(f,\alpha)$ lies in $S$ is finite, we have $|S| \leq \aleph_0|F[X]|=|F[X]|$.

**My question is how can I verify the last in equality?**

Answer (score 3):

We can write $S$ as a union of the following sets:
$$
\bigcup_{f\in F[X]\setminus\{0\}}\{\alpha\in E\colon f(\alpha)=0\}.
$$
Each of the sets appearing in the union is finite. Symbolically, we may write
$$
\bigl|\{\alpha\in E\colon f(\alpha)=0\}\bigr|<\aleph_0.
$$
Now we use the fact that cardinality is subadditive, so that
$$
|S|\leq \sum_{f\in F[X]}\aleph_0.
$$